# Firebase project error TypeError: targetNames.join is not a function

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-tools

Hi I am following this guide: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-firebase-chat/#2
and when I want to 'firebase deploy' then I get this error:

```
TypeError: targetNames.join is not a function
at deploy (C:\Users\grzeg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\index.js:68:57)
at Command._action (C:\Users\grzeg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\commands\deploy.js:47:12)
at C:\Users\grzeg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\command.js:176:29
at tryCatch (C:\Users\grzeg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:539:12)
at invokeCallback (C:\Users\grzeg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:554:13)
at publish (C:\Users\grzeg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:522:7)
at flush (C:\Users\grzeg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:2414:5)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: problem solved. I didnt deploy in correct way <,<

Comment: I am also facing same the issue

Comment: Can you tell me the correct way to deploy?

Comment: when u use firebase init. u need to click space to check option which u wanna choose, then delpoy will work correctly

Answer (score 8):

I also faced the same issue. It's because of my firebase.json file is empty. Once I specified the directory which needs to be upload in the JSON file, it worked.  For more details 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying

Comment: if you use functions you'll need to init them like this: `firebase init functions`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing, I simply forgot to use space to select which service I wanted to deploy to.